# choosing from multiple css files using media query based on screen resolution

Tags: html, css, layout, media-queries

I want to target my website for different screen resolutions (example: 1600x1200, 1366x768 etc) i presently have multiple css files which i load using jquery/javascript based on the screen.height and screen.width obtained.

Is there a way by which I can use the media attribute in the stylesheet link on my HTML5 page and implement the same behavior as obtained using jquery/javascript method? Something as given below:

```
<link href="/css/layout.css" media="screen and (device-height:768px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/css/layout1600x1200.css" media="screen and (device-height:1200px) and (device-width:1600px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I also need to load a default css file in case the clients' resolution does not match the conditions mentioned in above media query

Answer (score 2):

you could do this inside your master css file based on the screen

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) 
{
   /* your imports */
   @import url('/css/styles1.css');
   @import url('/css/styles2.css');
}
```